# How to turn English sentence into question formation

Tags: interrogatives

How do I convert basic sentence ("There remains one question.")  into a interrogative sentence? I appreciate your answer in advance.

Is it  "Does there remain one question?"  Or   "Does one question remain there?"  .

Answer (score 1):

"Does there remain one question?" is correct, but I think "Does one question remain?" is better.

Adding "there" to my suggested version would be incorrect unless the context supplies the reference of "there."